# Volley.How do I toast the error message received when authentication is failed after POSTing login credentials to an API in Android Studio Java?

Tags: android, json, rest, android-volley

This is the response I get when the authentication is not successful.

```
{
    "message": "The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later."
}
```

How do I toast this message in error response listener? Thanks.

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is used for questions/issues regarding the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Here's the answer in case if someone needs it.

```
try {
       NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
       String responseData = new String(response.data,"UTF-8");
       JSONObject responseObject =new  JSONObject(responseData);
       String message = responseObject.optString("message");
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```